# How to know if current time is between two timespans?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timespan

I have two time spans like so:

```
TimeSpan Starttime : 16:37:00
TimeSpan EndTime: 17:37:00
```

current time:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan now = currentDate.TimeOfDay;
```

**Problem**:

I can't figure out how to know if the current time is between starttime and endtime. i want to send mesages only between those two timespans.

How do i do this?

My attempt:

```
 if(startTime.Hours < now.Hours && endTime.Hours > now.Hours)
   // do stuff
```

This does not cover all scenarios since I need it to be exactly between starttime and endtime to the last second but I dont know how to do this.

Comment: I often get confused by `>` and `<` with dates. The way i remember it... **later is greater.**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can just use:

```
if (startTime < now && now < endTime)
```

Note that:

- This doesn't check the date; doesn't look like that's an issue here
- Depending on why you're doing this, you may want to consider intervals such as "10pm-2am" at which point you effectively want to reverse the logic
- In most cases, it's worth making the lower-bound inclusive and the upper-bound exclusive, e.g.

  ```
  if (startTime <= now && now < endTime)
  ```

  That's useful because then you can have several intervals where the end of one interval is the start of the next interval, and any one time is in exactly one interval.

To handle the "10pm-2am" example, you'd want something like:

```
if (interval.StartTime < interval.EndTime)
{
    // Normal case, e.g. 8am-2pm
    return interval.StartTime <= candidateTime && candidateTime < interval.EndTime;
}
else
{
    // Reverse case, e.g. 10pm-2am
    return interval.StartTime <= candidateTime || candidateTime < interval.EndTime;
}
```

Comment: I overcomplicated this it would seem. Thank you for the fast reply!

one question if i may: "Depending on why you're doing this, you may want to consider intervals such as "10pm-2am" at which point you effectively want to reverse the logic" Why would the logic need to be reversed here? starttime would be larger than now and the code within the if bracket would not execute

Comment: "This doesn't check the date". What do you mean? My understanding is that DateTime comparators just did a Ticks comparison. Preceding dates should have lower Ticks values for any given time.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN: If `startTime` is 10pm and `endTime` is 2am, you *actually* want anything from 10pm to midnight, and separately midnight to 2am. The simplest way to do that is potentially to check whether it's within 2am to 10pm and then reverse that result.

Comment: @itsme86: The point is that we're getting rid of the date - this is *only* dealing with time-of-day values. In many situations checking intervals you also care about the date, but I'm assuming that's out of scope for this specific question.

Comment: Date is out of scope, @Jon Skeet you are correct.
If it is not to much to ask, would you mind implementing the logic in your previous comment?.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN I think you'd have to add an additional modifier like `bool overNight=false; //default` and then your if statement would be `if((startTime<now && now<endTime) || (overNight && !(startTime<now && now<endTime))`

Comment: @Ra3IDeN You could programatically set `overNight = startTime>endTime` or get rid of the variable completely by just replacing it with `startTime>endTime` in the if statement I gave in my previous comment.